# use Facebook OpenGraph with a custom Facebook button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I want to add Facebook OpenGraph tags to my page, but I also want to stick with the style of Facebook Like button that I currently have (a custom image tag).

The [OpenGraph plugin instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) suggest you have to use Facebook's own Like button styles, and the customization options are limited.

Is there any way I can apply the Facebook Like code to my own image button?

UPDATE: to be clear, what I mean is that I have an image on my page that links to `https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?...`. I don't have a standard Facebook Like button. Will this mean that the OpenGraph tags on my page don't actually do anything?

Answer (score 1):

The old sharer.php endpoint will read the same meta tags as the Like button - when shared, the Facebook crawler accesses your site and pulls the metadata for the post (image, description, etc)

If you want to generate some sample metadata there's a form on the [like button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) (see 'step 2') to output tags in the correct format.

Use the [Debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see what tags Facebook detects on your site.

Answer (score 0):

It's against facebook's policies to try and replicate or re-create the like button.

Adding open graph tags won't affect your page, but they will improve how it appears when shared or liked in Facebook.

You may create a button called share which opens the feed dialog (sharer.php is deprecated) but you must use the real like button, not a custom image tag.